# Too many symbolic links error

Tags: directory, symbolic-link, tar

I am attempting to use LFS to make my own distro (for fun, nothing important) but keep running into issues. As it suggests, I am running a non-admin user account. However, every time I attempt to untar something it returns these errors:

```
tar (child): bzip2: Cannot exec: Too many levels of symbolic links
tar (child): Error is not recoverable: exiting now
tar: Child returned status 2
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

Also, when I try to run `mkdir`, I get this error

```
mkdir: cannot create directory '/tools/lib': Too many levels of symbolic links
```

Any ideas? If it helps, I am working on a separate partition mounted under '/mnt/lfs', and I can access it through `$LFS` (by running `export LFS=/mnt/lfs`) but I always access it through `cd`ing to `/mnt/lfs`.

Thanks in advance for the help

Answer (score 1):

In my case, when I had correctly chown'd the directories, somehow I ended up having the this happen when doing an ls -la of /

```
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root    11 Jun 13 01:44 tools -> tools/
```

Once I completed the following, I was able to unpack bin-utils and go on my way to making the LFS.

```
sudo su
cd /
rm tools
ln -s /mnt/tools/ tools
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that in my case, $LFS was /mnt/

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to my own question. If anyone else is wondering, I just had to chown the directories to my user, then all the problems were solved.